# What is the "NOCONFIG" value?

Tags: cmake

I was looking at generated PackageConfig.cmake files for external libraries I am using and I often saw things like:

```
set_property(TARGET Package::lib APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS NOCONFIG)
set_target_properties(Package::lib PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_NOCONFIG "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/liblib.so.1.1.1"
    IMPORTED_SONAME_NOCONFIG "liblib.so.1"
)
```

What exactly is this value used for?

Comment: You have found given code in the `*-noconfig.cmake` scripts, haven't you? See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960497/what-are-the-cmake-install-noconfig-scripts-for-ie-xxxtarget-noconfig-cmake).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm afraid that I don't understand your question. This is from TinyXML2's library. It has tinyxml2Config.cmake and tinyxml2Targets.cmake, but no file name with tinyxml2-noconfig.cmake. 

I saw the other question before. From my understanding, it just means that there are no defined configurations? This would resolve to `IMPORTED_LOCATION`?